# How to get all values from a Collection in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, collections, dictionary

My Java code has a map like

```
Map<Integer, someObject> abc = new HashMap<String, someObject>();
```

Some object has some properties that I need to print

I need to print only the values from a map.

JSP code

```
<c:forEach items="${abc .values()}" var="row">   
          <td>${row.someValue}<td>   
</c:forEach>
```

but it printing some gibberish as the values() returns a collection and it is not able to iterate it properly. Is there a way I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

What does it return when you do this?

```
<c:forEach items="${abc}" var="row">   
     <td>${row.values}</td>   
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: It is printing gibberish as the values are some Objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume the space between abc and .values() is a typo when entering into stackoverflow, as that would cause an issue.

If someObject has getter/setters for your properties, then it should work like this:

```
class SomeObject {
...
    String getSomeValue() {
        return someValue;
    }
}

<c:forEach items="${abc.values()}" var="row">   
    <td>${row.someValue}<td>   
</c:forEach>
```

---

If on the otherhand it doesn't have getter/setters then it will be like this (where you have to add the parenthesis):

```
class SomeObject {
...
    String someValue() {
        return "blah blah";
    }
}

<c:forEach items="${abc.values()}" var="row">   
    <td>${row.someValue()}<td>   
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I am not really sure why I was getting some random gibberish value. It worked now when I tried rebuilding my project(I was making change in the temp directory and refreshing the page). Thanks for the help.